# sql server query order by with union and replacing multiple columns' null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, plsql

I have a query to get records from 4 different tables. I am using `union` to get the final records. My problem is I don't have same number and type of columns in all 4 tables so I am making dummy columns with `null` value. The problem I am facing is in sorting. I am sorting records using datetime desc, but some times when dates are same then I want the secondry sort column on alerts that can be of High, Medium or Null types. I want Null columns on bottom but I am getting on top. So I tried to use `ISNULL(column_name, 'aaaa')` in `ORDER BY` clause, but I am not getting actual result. Can any one help?

```
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , null AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblA
union  
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , null AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblB
union  
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , null AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblC
union
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , Alert_Type FROM TblD
ORDER BY CreatedDt, ISNULL (Alert_Type,'aa') DESC
```

The error is

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
```

Thank you..

Comment: Can you share the query?

Comment: @Vikdor and NG - I have posted

Comment: Um. Do you need a solution for *both* SQL Server and Oracle? (`plsql` is Oracle's dialect of SQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Alert_Type` can't be NULL in `TblD`, you could do this:

```
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , 'aa' AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblA
union  
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , 'aa' AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblB
union  
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , 'aa' AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblC
union
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , Alert_Type FROM TblD
ORDER BY CreatedDt DESC, Alert_Type DESC
```

Note the `DESC` after `CreatedDt` (because you said you wanted to sort by the datetime column in descending order).

Comment: I tried it, but in this case it is not working as it is not giving priority to sort by CreatedDt in desc order. I want sort by CreatedDt primarily and if CreatedDt is same for more than one records than only sort by Alert_Type desc

Comment: @DevendraGohil The ordering of rows produced by this query is equivalent to yours. If you want to sort CreatedDt descendingly, insert `desc` after `ORDER BY CreatedDt`.

Comment: @DevendraGohil: I updated my answer to show how you can specify the descending order for the primary sorting criterion. (Missed that bit in your post, sorry.)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
select * from (

SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , null AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblA
union  
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , null AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblB
union  
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , null AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblC
union
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , Alert_Type FROM TblD)a
order by CreatedDt desc, 
         case when Alert_Type is null then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: Thanks. But Alert_Type column is not exists in TblA, TblB and TblC so for union clause I have made dummy column [Alert_Type] with null value in select queries. Your solution is giving me the same error "Invalid column name 'Alert_Type'.ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator."

Comment: @DevendraGohil: That cannont happen, did you copy my full query and executed it.. check this link for an example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2410

Comment: @DevendraGohil - Please post your amended query. This approach ought to work fine. I think you probably missed something in implementing it your end.

Comment: @MartinSmith It seems that expression referencing columns is not allowed in `order by` following `union` query. I couldn't confirm that in documentation though.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović - It's fine if the union is in a derived table as here and the order by outside though.

Answer (score 1):

you can still use `CASE` in your `ORDER BY` clause

```
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN column_name IS NULL
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END ASC --, other sorts
                  -- in these case NULL columns should be on the bottom part
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried like SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , null AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblA
union  
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , null AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblB
union  
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , null AS [Alert_Type] FROM TblC
union
SELECT CreatedDt as 'Date/Time' , Alert_Type FROM TblD
ORDER BY CreatedDt, column_name IS NULL THEN 1 END DESC but getting error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
"